# Getting the numerical value of a capacitor's impedance

Tags: circuit-analysis, impedance, capacitance

[image]

I understand that the impedance of a capacitor is \$\frac{1}{j\omega C}\$. For the circuit above, I have

\$\frac{1}{Z_V} = \frac{1}{Z_{V1}} + \frac{1}{Z_{V2}} + j\omega C_V\$

and

\$V_V = \frac{Z_V}{Z_V + \frac{1}{j\omega C_{CV}}}V_C\$

Are my equations correct?

Also, since the impedance of a capacitor has an imaginary component, how do I get a numerical value for \$Z_V\$, i.e. without the \$j\$?

Answer (score 1):

Your equations look right (did not break out pencil and paper but just inspecting), when you solve for an impedance. You will get a real and imaginary part, just drop the \$j\$ on the imaginary part, and solve for \$C\$ using an omega (the capacitance you seek will depend on the frequency of operation since \$\omega =2\pi f\$)

Answer (score 1):

The impedance of an ideal capacitor is entirely imaginary. The combination will be complex (real and imaginary parts). You can simplify it to a real and imaginary part- remember to multiply top and bottom by complex conjugate to get rid of j in the denominator.

It's not clear to me what you mean by Zv 'without the j', but if you want the real part, just simplify it and drop the imaginary part, but if you need the magnitude of the impedance, it's just the sum of the two in quadrature:

if \$Z = a + bj \$ then \$|Z| = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\$

In the case of a capacitor by itself, the magnitude is just |b| since a is 0.

If you want the voltage across the part to the right, just use the resistor voltage divider equation with the complex impedances and simplify. The magnitude will give you the voltage across 'Zv', and the angle \$ \theta= \tan^{-1}{(\frac{b}{a})}\$ will tell you the phase.

Comment: Can you help me out with the math? Given \$Z_{V1} = Z_{V2} = 100\Omega, Z_{C_{CV}} = Z_{C_V} = 2000/j = -2000j\$, and \$V_V/V_C = 0.04789\$. I have calculated \$1/Z_V = 1/Z_{V1} + 1/Z_{V2} + 1/Z_{C_V} = 0.01 + 0.01 + j/2000\$. Then \$|1/Z_V| = \sqrt{0.02^2 + (1/2000)^2} = 0.02\$, \$Z_V = 50\Omega\$

Comment: Then to calculate \$V_V/V_C\$, I got \$V_V/V_C = Z_V / (Z_V + Z_{C_{CV}}) = 50 / (50 - 2000j)\$. So to simplify the calculation, I took the reciprocal  \$V_C/V_V = (50 - 2000j) / 50 = 1 - 40j\$, and \$|V_C/V_V| = \sqrt{1 + 40^2} = 40.01\$, and so  \$V_V/V_C = 0.02499\$, which is about half of the value given. What did I miss in my calculations?